# How does an Azure Logic app compare to Workflow Foundation & WCF hosting in IIS to Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-logic-apps

To several developers on my team, they describe Azure Logic Apps as an evolution of Workflow Foundation.

In addition, WCF services hosted in IIS are more evolved on Service Fabric.

Are these analogies correct? Are better ones available?

Answer (score 9):

Azure Logic Apps is a Platform as a Service offering to give you simple integration with a number of connectors (from SaaS to on-premises databases like DB2) out of the box.  Optimized for cloud scale, simple deployments, and platform capabilities like retry policies and alerting.

It's a little challenging when drawing the comparison between Workflow Foundation and Azure Logic Apps.  From a basic workflow perspective they both have similar capabilities that have control flow, scopes and call outs to actions/activities.  WF is a framework so it gives you certain control over the host and storage configuration for persistence, and allows for interacting with MSDTC for local ACID transactional resources and closely coupled to WCF -- where Logic Apps is cloud hosted so you don’t need to be concerned with how to host or scale the Logic App.

Also it’s a cloud based service which relies on communication via REST for describing APIs and, as a cloud based service, relies on eventual consistency and idempotent calls instead of distributed transactions.

I guess in short I'd summarize in that yes, many scenarios that people would have historically used workflow foundation for could now use Logic Apps (and those scenarios get many advantages from the platform), but it's a different level of control and approach -- similar almost to an Azure Web Site vs. VM with IIS.